# Cannot invoke getTotal() on the array type double[][]?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I'm trying to get the total of a double array and I wrote out a class already. (Pictured below)

```
public class ArrayProcessing
{
    
    public double getTotal(double[][]a)
    {
        double total = 0;
    
        for(int i=0; i < a.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j < a[i].length; j++)
            {
                total += a[i][j];
            }
        }
        return total;   
    }

    public double getAverage(double[][]a)
    {    
        return getTotal(a) / a.length;
    }

}
```

My main program looks like this so far.

```
public class Demo {

        public static void main(String [] args)
        {
            double[][]numbers = new double[4][4];

            numbers.getTotal();
        }
}
```

I'm trying to initialize numbers as a double array and create a new instance of it. My question is why does `numbers.getTotal();` not work?

Comment: Because arrays don't have methods. You need to call the method on an instance of your class `ArrayProcessing`.

Answer (score 0):

That method is not defined on `Array`. In Java, there is no way to add custom methods to an `Array`. The way this is written, you would have to create an instance of `ArrayProcessing` first:

```
ArrayProcessing processor = new ArrayProcessing();
processor.getTotal(numbers);
```

It would be better to declare `getTotal` as `static` because then you would be able to directly call:

```
ArrayProcessing.getTotal(numbers);
```

Which is the common way to use Java utility classes.